# Is there another way than dot notation?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following document:

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("4eb28bd60078621a7d0000aa"),
   "metadata":{
      "xuuid":{
         "scope":"g",
         "version":1,
         "uuid":"0c1969c55b0241bfa3d37c6ceb900bba"
      },
      "custom":[

      ],
      "file":{
         "staticDataProviderId":4,
         "contentType":"factsheet",
         "name":"hugos tagebuch",
         "size":2345,
         "source":"bamldocuments",
         "mimeType":"application/pdf",
         "created":1319623020,
         "modified":1319623020,
         "accessed":1349623020,
         "locales":[
            "EN_us",
            "CH_fr"
         ],
         "countries":[
            "CH"
         ],
         "status":"published"
      },
      "links":[
         {
            "type":"instrument",
            "key":5
         },
         {
            "type":"instrument",
            "key":3
         }
      ]
   },
   "chunkSize":262144,
   "length":14,
   "md5":"2dd900d9be40e2dd3fc69cc77c14726c"
}
```

I can find it by the following query:

```
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.links":{"type":"instrument","key":5}})
```

But I want to have somtehing like that (doesn't match my document, cause of other keys in metadata):

```
db.fs.files.find({"metadata"{"links":{"type":"instrument","key":5}}})
```

As background, in my PHP code i want to have a "find" function which gets a criteria applied only in metadata and so I need something not so nice like:

```
public function find(array $criteria)
{
   $extendedCriteria = array();
   foreach($criteria as $key => $value) {
      $extendedCriteria['metadata.'.$key => $value]; 
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: can you clarify?  What do you want the second query to do? Find records where {"type":"instrument","key":5} is the only object in the field metadata.links?

Answer (score 0):

Toward the end of [the page on dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) they mention the $elemMatch operator which can be used like so:

```
db.foo.find({foo: {"$elemMatch": {shape: "square", color: "purple"}}})
```

...to match a "foo" element with a field shape that has the value "square" and a field color that has the value "purple".

I'm not 100% sure this will do what you want, but check it out.